# Using Spark to read from a Rest API I Cannot get the UUIDs to serialize into the mapPartition function

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am attempting to read from a Rest API using Spark by getting a list of UUIDs off of S3 in a dataframe. Calling uuids.mapPartitions then building my API calling java object in the map and for each uuid in the partition getting a List. These strings are related UUIDs.

I need to return a dataset/dataframe which I can write out to parquet which has a schema similar to

```
{ uuida : [uuid1, uuid2, uuid3 ... ], uuidb : [uuid1, uuid2, uuid3 ... ], uuidc : [uuid1, uuid2, uuid3 ... ] }
```

Right now I have the following code:

```
import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._
def calculate(unit_attributes: DataFrame ): DataFrame = {
val unit_uuids = unit_attributes
  .filter(col("isEnabled") =!= 1)
  .select(col("unit_uuid"))
val unit_uuids_ds = unit_uuids.as(Encoders.STRING)

val relatedSets = unit_uuids_ds
  .mapPartitions(
    iterator => {
    val column1 = StructField("related_uuid", StringType, nullable = false)
    var schema = StructType(Array(column1))
    var relatedSetAPI = new RestClient(clientId, clientSecret, relatedSetHost)
    var relatedSetPart = iterator.map( unit => {
      val relatedSetUuidsList = relatedSetAPI.getRelatedUnits(unit)
      val seqUuids = JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(relatedSetUuidsList.iterator()).asScala.toSeq
      val rows = seqUuids.map{ u =>  Row(u:_*)}
      val rdd = sparkSession.sparkContext.makeRDD(rows)
      val df = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
      df.withColumn("unit_uuid", lit(unit))
    })

    relatedSetPart
  }).toDF()

relatedSets
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
[INFO]       .mapPartitions(
[INFO]                     ^
```

This was marked as a duplicate however it is not solved by the linked questions despite the same error message. The encoder error message is a bit of a red herring. The solution has nothing to do with changing the data in the dataset only with updating to remove the references to the sparkSession which is present in the driver.

The final code looks like this:

```
  def calculate(unit_attributes: DataFrame): DataFrame = {

val unit_uuids = unit_attributes
  .filter(col("isEnabled") =!= 1)
  .col("unit_uuid")
  .limit(10000)

val relatedSets = unit_uuids
  .mapPartitions(
    iterator => {
      val column1 = StructField("related_uuid", StringType, nullable = false)
      var schema = StructType(Array(column1))
      var competativeSetAPI = new RestClient(clientId, clientSecret, relatedSetHost)
      iterator.map(unit => {
        val relatedSetUuidsList = relatedSetAPI.getRelatedUnits(unit.getAs[String]("unit_uuid"))
        val seqUuids = JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(relatedSetUuidsList.iterator()).asScala.toSeq
        UnitRelatedSet(unit.getAs[String]("unit_uuid"), seqUuids)
      })
    }).toDF()

relatedSets
}
```

Comment: You need to import implicits._ from the Spark session object

Comment: I have that already

Comment: This is a duplicate -- your protest is incorrect in it's assumptions about how SO works. Your edit should be written as another answer to the 'duplicate'.